# ArrayList type inference

Tags: java

I would like to use the ArrayList constructor:

```
ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)
```

as follows.

```
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<>(); 

List<Number> ln = new ArrayList<>(li); // won't compile.. Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<Integer> to List<Number>
```

I don't understand the compiler error.

However, the following compiles fine.

```
List<Number> ln = new ArrayList<Number>(li);
```

What am I missing? Using java 7

Comment: Can someone try this on Java8? Maybe target type inference has been improved?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Java creates a new object of type ArrayList<Integer>. This cannot be assigned to a variable of type List<Number>, since Integer is not exactly the same as Number. You must use a wildcard like so:

```
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<>(); 
List<? extends Number> ln = new ArrayList<>(li);
```

This allows a list of generic type Integer, which extends Number, to be assigned to a variable of type List<Number>. Look here for more information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: How does java create an ArrayList<Integer>? Is this logic documented somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. If you are asking why Java chose to create an ArrayList<Integer> instead of an ArrayList<Number>, this is because the type of li is ArrayList<Integer>, and the language infers the type from the type of li. If the type of li were List<? extends Number>, then you'd be able to make the assignment.

Comment: I should add that you can see this in the signature of the constructor: ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c). In this case, the E comes from the generic type of li. When li is List<? extends Number>, the E is just Number.

Comment: Yes.. It's the E in Collection<? extends E> that helps the compiler to infer the type of ArrayList<E>. :) I was missing this point.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the "diamond operator".

```
List<Number> ln = new ArrayList<>(li);
```

gets expanded to

```
List<Number> ln = new ArrayList<Integer>(li);
```

which does not compile.

You can fix it by being more explicit:

```
List<Number> ln = new ArrayList<Number>(li);
```

Comment: How exactly does that expansion happen? li is just a constructor argument.

Comment: @user2953113: I am not sure... But the `Integer` part must be coming from `li` (which has to be made to match the constructor signature, and the available options are `Integer`, `Number`, `Object`, `Serializable`, `Comparable`. I suppose the language spec calls for just using the object type itself).

Comment: Got an idea about how the expansion happens. The E in the constructor (<? extends E>) is linked to the E in ArrayList<E>. In the case of li, E becomes Integer and ArrayList<E> becomes ArrayList<Integer>.

Comment: Yes. But it could also become `Number` (which would be better here). I don't know what the spec for this is.